# Wireless working but for the system the device is not in use and does not work!

Tags: drivers, wireless

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 and during the installation I connected my wireless card to my network.
At the next reboot everything ok and card connected then I launched the search for additional third-party drivers for my Nvidia.
To my surprise scrolling down I saw that despite my model of realtek wireless card it was recognized but under it was written "the device is not working" and and "do not use the device" was selected but everything worked great.
Attached the screenshot.
Is it a bug or am I the one who does not understand the meaning?
Finally, however, I chose to use the DKMS driver.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This window shows that 3-rd party drivers using DKMS are not installed.

The device is working with in-tree drivers.

The message is really confusing, but everything is OK.

Comment: From experience it works much better with the `rtl8821ce-dkms` driver.